# How to set the JNDI context in SAP NWDS

Tags: jakarta-ee, netweaver

I am using NetWeaver Developer Studio. I tried to create the context for JNDI but the initial context is not setting up properly. I tried using the `com.sap.engine.services.jndi.InitialReplicatingContextFactoryImpl` but I keep getting this error:

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class

What needs to be done in this case?

Answer (score 1):

We use these two properties when running tests outside netweaver:

java.naming.factory.initial=com.sap.engine.services.jndi.InitialContextFactoryImpl              java.naming.provider.url={our nw host}:50004

-tim